# Compress Symfony Response

Tags: php, symfony, security, shopware6, shopware6-app

Good morning,

I am working on a shop running on the Shopware 6 platform. We are currently optimizing PageSpeed Insights, one of the recommendations is to enable text compression.

The application runs on platform.sh, where in the documentation we can read:

> Response compression reduces payload sizes and generally increases your app's response times. Dynamic responses generated by your app aren't compressed because of a general security issue. While your app can compress its own response, doing so when the response includes any user-specific information, including a session cookie, opens up an attack vector over SSL/TLS connections. For that reason, you generally shouldn't compress generated responses.

However, I found such a package: https://github.com/middlewares/encoderAnd I think I could easily implement this in Symfony/Shopware to compress my responses directly into the application.

Is it good idea? Is it safe?

Comment: In my opinion you should have a look at fastly for example. Fastly can also compress the responses and is also not using application ressources for that. To be honest, for me this is not something the application should do, but the infrastructure. 

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/reverse-http-cache#configure-fastly

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't just activate compression (f.e. gzip) on your nginx, apache or whatever?

Comment: Because I'm using platform.sh and can't access apache or nginx or whatever :)